# Laravel 8 Unit Testing - assertJson() how to capture it in controller

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I have a laravel 8 Unit Test which looks like this:

```
public function testAddingTwoCars()
{
    $response = $this->postJson('api/basket', ['cars' => [['name' => 'car one'], ['name' => 'car two']]]);
    $response
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJson(['total' => 40]);
}
```

In my route I have:

```
Route::post('/api/basket',[basketController::class, 'store']);
```

In my controller I have:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

when I run the test with `php artisan test` it shows this:

```
 • Tests\Unit\BasketTest > adding two cars
 Unable to find JSON:                                        
                                                                                                                                                    
 [{                                                          
     "total": 40                                             
 }]                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                      
 within response JSON:                                       
                                                        
 [{                                                          
   "cars": [                                           
     {                                                   
         "name": "car one"                                 
     },                                                  
     {                                                   
         "name": "car two"                                 
     }                                                   
   ]                                                       
 }].
```

How do I:grab the total as its not in `$request` so that I could do something like this in my controller:

```
$public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $data['total'] = 40;
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

The above works, but it is hard coded so is not the best way to do it

Comment: Where does the "total" key come from?

Comment: i'm not sure, that's all ive got to work from

Comment: in the unit test it just says $response
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJson(['total' => 40]); @TZiebura

Comment: Your controller method does not provide the 'total' key to $data variable at best it will contain the 'cars' json, so I think you're missing logic in your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assertJson`

Assert that the response contains the given JSON data:

```
$response->assertJson(array $data, $strict = false);
```

The `assertJson` method converts the response to an array and utilizes `PHPUnit::assertArraySubset` to verify that the given array exists within the JSON response returned by the application. So, if there are other properties in the JSON response, this test will still pass as long as the given fragment is present.

You can read about it at this link

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#assert-json

and Here

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/http-tests#testing-json-apis

and you can check this video too

https://adamwathan.me/2016/11/16/the-only-json-assertion-youll-ever-need/

Answer (score 0):

`->assertJson(['total' => 40])` is non-sense; this will not pass unless the JSON has it:

```
return response()->json(['data' => $data, 'total' => 40]);
```